# windows phone 8.1 NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles not updating

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

New to windows phone 8.1, so I am exploring what it can do.  Using the samples provided (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/windows-phone-81-samples-08631ca7) as well as a version of my own, I can deploy to my phone from visual studio and it works.  However, when I disconnect from my machine and try running the connection profile code, it doesn't update.  The code/result is the same for my and the samples project (code is below). I figured it was a permission thing, so I have checked everything but shared user certificates because of a bug I read about preventing deployments.  I know it is probably user error, but I am not seeing the issue.

```
IList<ConnectionProfile> nearbyRouters = new List<ConnectionProfile>();

var ConnectionProfiles =     Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
foreach (ConnectionProfile cp in ConnectionProfiles)
{
     nearbyRouters.Add(cp);
}
```

Comment: More specifically, when I move location and compare result to my wifi window under settings, they don't match.  It keeps returning the list I had when connected to my desktop 8.1 machine.

Comment: Tried this and still nothing:

Comment: String deviceSelector = Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
            DeviceInformationCollection devInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector);

Comment: I would like to get the list of nearby wifi hotspots...I can do this on the phone, but it seems like that API doesn't support this from what I can see.

Comment: For anyone else seeing this post, it looks like any information through the api is strictly limited to hotspots already connected.